# Is there a simple way to confirm an email address with Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm using sendgrid to send an email from within Dialogflow.
Is there a way to easily confirm with the user their email address once they've said it? I was going to just split the email address up and repeat the characters back to the user eg. "t e s t @ t e s t dot com" 
But happy for advice.

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at using [SSML](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml)?

Not exactly sure what your desired output is but you could do something like

```
<speak>
  <say-as interpret-as="characters">test@test.com</say-as>
</speak>
```